# Network task in collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, mvp

I am using mvp pattern for my ios app. 
I got one view controller with table view in it. In its presenter i load array of items for cells to represent. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I am initing cells presenters and setting them to cells. The problem is that I need additional data that I can get only by running a network request with a field that is contained in the item. I tried to perform this request right after cell presenter is set, but this affects the smoothness of the scrolling. How should i do it correctly?
In view controller I got:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUp()
    presenter.loadAllDocuments()
}
```

then in presenter

```
    func loadAllDocuments() {
    documentService.loadAllDocuments { [weak self] documents in
        self?.documents = documents
        self?.cellPresenters = documents.compactMap { MaterialCellPresenter(with: $0) }
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self?.view.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if var cellPresenter = presenter.cellPresenters[indexPath.row] {
        cellPresenter.view = cell
        cell.presenter = cellPresenter
    }

    return cell
```

in table view cell I have

```
var presenter: MaterialCellPresenterProtocol! {
    didSet {
        setUp()
    }
}

private func setUp() {
    documentIcon.image = presenter.documentIcon
    documentTitle.text = presenter.displayName
    presenter.getDocumentInfo()
}
```

and finally in cell presenter

```
func getDocumentInfo() {
    if let id = document.questionID {
        documentService.question(with: id) { [weak self] question in
            self?.documentQuestion = question
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.view.updateDocumentInfo()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show code you tried

Comment: hope this code helps

Answer (score 0):

Cells can be deallocated immediately. A better practice is to perform the network request in the model.

- Move the network request code into the model class or struct.
- In the model declare a closure to update the view.
- In `cellForRow` assign the closure of the current model item to an optional property in the cell.
- When the data is available call the closure in the model.
- You can even cancel the network request in `tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)` if necessary.